# Custom long running task scheduler in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core, thread-safety

So i'm about to create a custom long running task scheduler (fancy foreground thread that manages tasks and talk to the db), and yes i'm aware of the alternatives yet nothing really fits my exact requirements.

i am worried that the asp .net will kill the app domain and my thread with it, or even kill the individual tasks that this thread manages

so i'm asking for a workaround to be able to have some control over when the app domain gets destroyed or to have this running in the same asp.net core app and not being influenced by the framework

i'm pretty flexible when it comes to kestrel or iis, windows or linux, etc.. but i still need this to run from within the application rather than having it as a separate service or app

Comment: Look in to [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.0) built in to asp.net core.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i did, the cancellation token/request only gives you few seconds to terminate, and there is no where in the documentation where it allows you to override this behavior and take control of when the app domain gets destroyed

Comment: Given the nondeterministic nature of clean up during the application termination it's gonna be difficult irrelevant of the technology used. You could save input state at the beginning of each task and rerun it once the service is up again, if the task hasn't completed successfully. Difficult to say anything specific without knowing the details.

Comment: It depends on how you are hosting. For example on Azure you would set the app service setting "always on" and it should not call stop on the service.

Comment: `i'm pretty flexible when it comes to kestrel or iis` Then your problem is solved. The lifetime management comes from IIS and asp.net. If you run your webapplication as standalone with asp.net core/kestrel you won't have any issue